# How can I destroy an ActiveRecord with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

What I want to do is destroy a specific ActiveRecord from jQuery, which is within an .html.erb file that has the record I want to destroy as an instance variable (@connection). I tried various attempts with jQuery.ajax, but nothing worked. Any help is much appreciated.

I thought the fix worked, but it didn't. I got this, which works if I run it in the javascript console:

```
$.ajax({
  type:"DELETE",
  url:"<%= connection_path(@connection) %>",
  success: function(msg){
    alert("disconnected");
  }
});
```

But when its supposed run in my javascript it does not. I'm so confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to create the `destroy` action in your connection controller, which will receive the connection id. Then in your view call that action using `@connection.id` as the parameter.

**Edit**

For the JQuery part, you can use something like this:

```
$.post(<%= destroy_connection_path(@connection) %>, {_method:'delete'}, null, "script");
```

Comment: What I want to do is call the destroy action from my javascript. I can't use `<%= link_to %>` or anything like that. What I don't know how to do that I need is an ajax call to call destroy, if that makes any sense.

Comment: @user1554194 AFAIK rails turns DELETE requests into POST requests with a `_method` parameter. Try with the edit I posted.